# Does updating the compaction min_threshold on table cause sstables to be rewritten?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

Does updating the compaction `min_threshold` and `max_threshold` on a table rewrite sstables? Just want to confirm since updating the compaction strategy would rewrite sstables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it wont. It changes the thresholds for how many sstables a compaction would include which may or may not do anything depending on previous settings and existing sstables. If you want to you can use `nodetool upgradesstables -a <keyspace> <table>` and it will rewrite each sstable.